# Unable to retrieve data from webpage

Tags: php, regex

I'm in middle of Rob Percival's complete web dev course and stuck at challenge Project: Weather Scraper. Trying to get weather info from a website, but not working. Thanks in advance

```
<?php
 $contents = file_get_contents("http://www.weather-forecast.com/locations/San-Francisco/forecasts/latest");

     preg_match('/3 Day Weather Forecast Summary:<\/b><span class="read-more-small"><span class="read-more-content"> <span class="phrase"> (.*?) </s', $contents, $matches);

 echo $matches[1];
?>
```

Comment: What error messages are you getting?  Are you able to access the website from your computer? Is there a link to the particular tutorial you are using?  Browsing [ask] is a good resource for getting the most out of your questions.

Comment: @jDo, he doesn't - if you look at the preg_match documentation you will see that the third parameter is actually declared by the preg_match function itself and will contain an array with the results of the regex (and I agree that this is a bit weird). http://php.net/manual/de/function.preg-match.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm taking the same course and finally figured out how to do this after an hour! Sorry if this is late, but I hope it helps anyone else looking for an answer.

I'm not sure why yours didn't work, but here is what worked for me:

```html
preg_match('/3 Day Weather Forecast Summary:<\/b><span class="read-more-small"><span class="read-more-content"> <span class="phrase">(.*?)<\/span>/',
        $contents, $matches);
        print_r($matches[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

There no whitespaces in html after `<span class="phrase">`.

Html from site:

```
3 Day Weather Forecast Summary:</b><span class="read-more-small"><span class="read-more-content"> <span class="phrase">Light rain (total 5mm)
```

Try this:

```
if (preg_match('/3 Day Weather Forecast Summary:<\/b><span class="read-more-small"><span class="read-more-content"> <span class="phrase">(.*?)</s', $contents, $matches)) { 
    echo $matches[1];
}
```

Comment: @DovidM it works for me. Also i try with http://phpfiddle.org/ and it works also..

Comment: That's weird. Just checked phpfiddle and it showed up correctly there, but when I looked it up on my site it just shows a blank screen. This is a link to it on my site, the only code on it is the php that ran on phpfiddle...    http://ideoinnectis.com/playground/php-files/scraper.php

Comment: Can you make `var_dump($contents);` there? plz

Comment: Added that. I don't see any difference in the page when I did that, is that to report errors? (sorry for dumb questions)

Comment: May be your php file is not execute at all? The first, make the simplest page <?php echo 'test';?>. If it is worked insert other code line by line.

Comment: The echo commands isn't working either. PHP is working fine on other pages in my site, in the same folder as this page though

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
3 Day Weather Forecast Summary:<\/b>\s*<span class="read-more-small">\s*<span class="read-more-content">\s*<span class="phrase">(.*?)<\/span>
```

It will deal with whitespace in between *any* of the tags.

<kbd>[**Live Demo on Regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/dC9eU2/2)</kbd>